# explode array of array- (Dataframe) pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  +-----+--------------------+
|index|              merged|
+-----+--------------------+
|    0|[[2.5, 2.4], [3.5...|
|    1|[[-1.0, -1.0], [-...|
|    2|[[-1.0, -1.0], [-...|
|    3|[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5...|
|    4|[[0.5, 0.5], [1.0...|
|    5|[[0.5, 0.5], [1.0...|
|    6|[[-1.0, -1.0], [0...|
|    7|[[0.0, 0.0], [0.5...|
|    8|[[0.5, 0.5], [1.0...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

And I want to explode the merged column into

```
+-----+-------+-------+
|index|Column1|Column2|
+-----+-------+-------+
|    0|    2.5|   2.4 |
|    1|    3.5|    0.5|
|    2|   -1.0|   -1.0|
|    3|   -1.0|   -1.0|
|    4|   0.0 |   0.0 |
|    5|    0.5|   0.74|
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Each tuple [[2.5, 2.4], [3.5,0,5]] repensente two columns, knowing that 2,5 and 3,5  will be stored in column 1 and (2.4,0,5) will be stored in second Column

So I tried this

```
df= df.withColumn("merged", df["merged"].cast("array<array<float>>"))
df= df.withColumn("merged",explode('merged'))
```

then i will apply a udf to create another DF

but i can't cast the data or apply explode, and I received the error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'cast(merged as array<array<float>)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast StringType to ArrayType(StringType,true)
```

I tried also

```
df= df.withColumn("merged", df["merged"].cast("array<string>"))
```

but nothing works
and if I apply explode without cast, I receive

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'explode(merged)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType;
```

Comment: can you give the schema of df? it looks like merged is actually a string, not what you have in argument. You can use `split` to split a string by a separator. Also, it seems like there are typos in your question: isn't index the same for exploded values in your exemple of expected result? Or is what you gave what you really want?

Comment: Thx, I re read my code, and I found that I forgot to add return type  ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())) in my lambda function (who merge my columns)

Comment: so... problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext                        
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession                               

from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, StringType, IntegerType   
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col                         


def col1_calc(merged):                                             
    return merged[0][0]                                            

def col2_calc(merged):                                             
    return merged[0][1]                                            

if __name__ == '__main__':                                         
    spark = SparkSession \                                         
        .builder \                                                 
        .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \    
        .getOrCreate()                                             

    df = spark.createDataFrame([                                   
        (0, [[2.5,2.4],[3.5]]),                                    
        (1, [[-1.0,-1.0],[3.5]]),                                  
        (2, [[-1.0,-1.0],[3.5]]),                                  
    ], ["index", "merged"])                                        

    df.show()                                                      

    column1_calc = udf(col1_calc, FloatType())                     
    df = df.withColumn('Column1', column1_calc(df['merged']))      
    column2_calc = udf(col2_calc, FloatType())                     
    df = df.withColumn('Column2', column2_calc(df['merged']))      

    df = df.select(['Column1', 'Column2', 'index'])                
    df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+-----+
|Column1|Column2|index|
+-------+-------+-----+
|    2.5|    2.4|    0|
|   -1.0|   -1.0|    1|
|   -1.0|   -1.0|    2|
+-------+-------+-----+
```